# MYSQL Procedure : Loop over distinct values of Text column and create temporary tables

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

My subgroups table has

```
subgroup_abbr_str
AA
BB
BB
CC
DD
DD
DD
... and many more
```

I  want to create a temporary table for each of these values. Temporary Table AA, BB, CC and DD. Here is my initial code which creates table var instead of AA.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FLAGITERATION()
BEGIN
DECLARE totRows INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE startRow INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE var TEXT DEFAULT  NULL;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM subgroups INTO totRows ;
SET startRow=0;
WHILE startRow<totRows DO 
    SELECT DISTINCT subgroup_abbr_str FROM subgroups LIMIT startRow,1 INTO var ;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE var AS SELECT SUM(present)
    FROM trad_new;
  SET startRow = startRow + 1;
END WHILE;
End;
;;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It costs more time rebuilding sample data with all table as to correct programming errors

What you want to do could be done with dynamic sql.

Also you should use a cursor for the loop

> ```
> CREATE TABLE subgroups (subgroup_abbr_str VaRCHAR(2));
> INSERT INTO subgroups VALUES ('AA'),
> ('BB'),
> ('BB'),
> ('CC'),
> ('DD'),
> ('DD'),
> ('DD')
> ```

> ```
> CREATE tABLE trad_new (present INT)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO trad_new VALUEs (1)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE FLAGITERATION()
> BEGIN
>   DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
>   DECLARE _subgroup varchar(100) DEFAULT "";
>   -- declare cursor for subgroup_abbr_str
>   DEClARE cursubgroup 
>       CURSOR FOR 
>           SELECT DISTINCT subgroup_abbr_str FROM subgroups;
>
>   -- declare NOT FOUND handler
>   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
>         FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
>         
>   OPEN cursubgroup;
>
>   getsubgroup: LOOP
>       FETCH cursubgroup INTO _subgroup;
>       IF finished = 1 THEN 
>           LEAVE getsubgroup;
>       -- build taböe
>       SET @sql = CONCAT("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ",_subgroup," AS SELECT SUM(present)
>          FROM trad_new;");
>          PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
>          EXECUTE stmt;
>
>   END LOOP getsubgroup;
>   CLOSE cursubgroup;  
> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;  
> End
> ```

> ```
> call FLAGITERATION()
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM AA;
> ```
>
> ```
> | SUM(present) |
> | -----------: |
> |            1 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ea2740fce394212ae34c371083dccbdc)*

Comment: What are you using the statement below for ?

SET @a := _subgroup;

Comment: it is only a debug line,, which i used to check the flow of a program.